# angularjs create html with data binding based on object properties and template

Tags: angularjs, templates, object, dynamic, properties

I'm trying to create a html view in angularjs where the user can edit some values on an objects properties. I have a object of the model in a service and then i also have another object that describes the properties of the model object.

The description object has an array of objects called parameters and each object has properties such as name, description, type and so on like this:

```
{
"name": "item",
"description": "An item",
"parameters": [{
    "name": "prop1",
    "wasNullable": false,
    "description": "a property",
    "type": "string",
    "isRequired": true
}, {
    "name": "prop2",
    "wasNullable": true,
    "description": "a property",
    "type": "string",
    "isRequired": true
}]
```

}

Im want to use this data to build a view for the object that is to be manipulated. If the property name is a string i want to have an html-template with a text input and a label like this:

```
<label>{{ parameter.name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="parameter.description"></input>
```

I want to be able to have these "type templates" as separate html files.

Im having trouble on how to do this and handle data-binding. One path could be to do an ng-repeat on the parameters array on the description object something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="param in $ctrl.definitions.parameters">
<div ng-switch="param.primitiveType">
    <div ng-switch-when="string">
        <string></string>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="dateTime">
        <date-time></date-time>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="enum">
        <enum></enum>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="param.subTypes">
    <select ng-model="select.subType">
        <option ng-repeat="subType in property.subTypes">{{ subType.name }}</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-repeat="subType in property.subTypes">
        <properties type="subType" ng-if="select.subType === subType.name"></properties>
    </div>
</div>
```

This would solve my problem because i could use components for each type of property but i can't figure out how to do the databinding to another object that exists in a service.

Another way would be to add all the parameters with default values from the description object to the actual model object and then do ng-repeat on the referenced model object but then i can't have this solution of switching to the correct html template.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions but the closest to the code you provided should be passing data into your template `directives`.

This is actually one of the basics of using `directive`, you can pass data from parent like this:

```
<div ng-switch-when="string">
    <string param="param"></string>
</div>
<div ng-switch-when="dateTime">
    <date-time param="param"></date-time>
</div>
<div ng-switch-when="enum">
    <enum param="param"></enum>
</div>

.directive('string', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            param: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log($scope.param);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This would work if i didn't use one object that describes the properties and one object that is the actual model or instance that i want to change values on. In your example i would be binding the input to the description object, not the actual model. This would work if i used ng-repeat on the model object, but that would mean that i couldnt do the ng-switch depending on the parameter type property. Please excuse me if im not being very clear on what i mean.

Comment: @Kristofer Have you considered combining the 2 objects upon acquiring them and then let angular work on the single result object?

Comment: @lcycool Yes i thought about that but i could not figure out how the merge object should look or how i would handle the databinding in that case. Something like: 

{ 
"name" : "item",
"type" : "defaultType",
"parameters" : [
    "name" : "age",
    "description" : "The age.",
    "type" : "int",
    "value" : 0
]}

Maybe i could use the value field here to solve the data-binding.